# Same cable, different speed test results between two computers

Tags: linux, networking, router, ethernet, arch-linux

A strange issue which I would be grateful for assistance with, I seem to be getting different speeds on speedtests over the same Cat7 ethernet cable when plugged into two different computers. One of the machines is an old NEC laptop from around 2003 which is running Windows 7 and is a vastly slower computer in every way than my desktop which in comparison has an 850 Evo, Gigabyte Sniper b7 Motherboard, a gigabit Ethernet port and is running Manjaro Arch i3. However the slower computer running outdated software still manages a better internet connection over the exact same cable.

So far I have tried using a different cable, which produces the same results. I have also tried running Windows 10 on my desktop which yielded the same results. I have tried updating the motherboard drivers for the port while in Windows 10 to the latest version which also produced the same results.

The test server is of course the same and I have done multitudes of tests on both computers all with the same results however the old NEC laptop still seems to push out a lower ping and higher throughput than my vastly superior desktop machine.

As I mentioned my motherboard is a Gigabyte Sniper b7, I've looked through the BIOS settings and nothing screams to me that it would be affecting the speeds but test after test says otherwise. Perhaps someone with a better BIOS setting knowledge than me can point me in the right direction. That is all I think it could be, unless there is some compatibility issue between the router and my desktop port. The router also has gigabit ports although it is only an ADSL connection. I am aware that the marginal improvement will matter little however it is a waste to not be getting the full throughput of my connection.

Are there some settings I have overlooked which is affecting my connection?

Comment: Is the newer machine downloading updates or otherwise has a higher background level of data usage?

Comment: Nope, nothing else using the internet connection only speedtest.net running in Chrome. I thought it could be that, but there's nothing else on the machine running. I might add that I have been having this same issue for several days through multiple reboots and network conditions.

Comment: What difference are we talking about? Exact speed values would be helpful.

Comment: The Laptop is getting a consistent ping of 16 and the desktop a consistent ping of 26-27, the download speeds vary however the desktop is consistently 2-3 mbits slower. I would like to ignore it but my better hardware should not be giving me these results.

Comment: If you are just measuring download speed: The complete network stack can influence this, and if you add bufferbloat, it becomes quite complex. So different speeds on two very different OS are not that surprising. The cable will likely have no influence (and that's easy to test by measuring throughput through/from *the router*, e.g. with `iperf` if you have root access on the router).

Comment: I'll look into iperf thanks. I thought there would be some variation between OS's but considering that both Manjaro and Windows 10 produced exactly the same results when I installed them on the desktop machine I thought that it must be an issue with BIOS or drivers or something along those lines.

Comment: I have done an internal ping test and here are the results, although I don't think there is much in it. This was done through the router interface. The issue persists. https://pastebin.com/TAs5UBp7